# I am using the linkedin share button but the title, description and image are not displayed

Tags: button, share, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I am using the opengraph tags in the header of my page :

https://openlab.ecdys.fr/articles/sodexo-s-testimonial-about-the-collaborative-platform-ecdys-openlab

The url is is perfectly parsed by facebook and google but not by linkedin.
When i type the url in linkedin sharing message, i only get the following :

> openlab.ecdys.fr

The title, description and image are not displayed.
What is wrong ? Thanks a lot for your help

Below is the source code of the header :

```
   <html lang="fr" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
     <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
       <meta name = "robots", content = "all" />
       <meta name = "language", content = "fr" />
       <title>Sodexo&#39;s testimonial about the collaborative platform ECDYS OpenLab™ </title>    
<meta content="Sodexo Benefits and Rewards organized collaborative consultations using ECDYS OpenLab™. Betina Johnstone, Innovation Community Manager, presents the background, the objectives and her experience on this project !" name="description" />    
<meta content="co-innovation, Sodexo, Témoignage client, testimonial" name="keywords" />    
<meta content="website" property="og:type" />    
<meta content="Sodexo Benefits and Rewards organized collaborative consultations using ECDYS OpenLab™. Betina Johnstone, Innovation Community Manager, presents the background, the objectives and her experience on this project !" property="og:description" />    
<meta content="https://s3.amazonaws.com/innowaze_blog/uploads/article/illustration/33/Capture_d__cran_2015-03-11___10.40.36.png" property="og:image" />    <meta content="Sodexo&#39;s testimonial about the collaborative platform ECDYS OpenLab™ " property="og:title" />    
<meta content="summary_large_image" property="twitter:card" />   
<meta content="Sodexo&#39;s testimonial about the collaborative platform ECDYS OpenLab™ " property="twitter:title" />    
<meta content="Sodexo Benefits and Rewards organized collaborative consultations using ECDYS OpenLab™. Betina Johnstone, Innovation Community Manager, presents the background, the objectives and her experience on this project !" property="twitter:description" />    
<meta content="https://s3.amazonaws.com/innowaze_blog/uploads/article/illustration/33/Capture_d__cran_2015-03-11___10.40.36.png" property="twitter:image" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When LinkedIn's crawler encounters untrustable SSL certificates on a server, it will fail.  Your host, openlab.ecdys.fr, does appear to have an issue with it's certificate (https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://openlab.ecdys.fr)

Alternatively, you can make your content available over HTTP and you shouldn't see this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I forgot to install the intermediate certificate. I just add it and now it works perfectly.